# Applying footer HTML to multiple view without using _layout and Partial view is it possible in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to apply common UI component to multiple views in aspnet mvc except _Layout/Partial View

Comment: Could I ask why you don't want to use partial? Since this would be normally the logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

_Layout, Partial views, Display Templates, [Razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) (asp.net core) or [Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0)(For Blazor, asp.net core 3.0)